# How to check with jquery if Internet Explorer is running in Compatibility View

Tags: jquery, galleria

Since jQuery.browser is deprecated and jQuery.support is the recommended tool to tackle browser issues, what's the recommended way to handle the following problem?

The Fullscreen theme of the Galleria jquery plugin doesn't work properly (wrong image positioning) in IE < 8 and in IE 8 and 9 compatibility view mode. Doctype is HTML 5, and turning off that mode with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

does its job, but **how do I use jQuery.support properly do check if the IE version is < 8 *or* the compatibility view is somehow still turned on** (because then we use another theme for these users)?

Update: Here's the code we use now (at the bottom of the html).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8) {
            Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            $("#gallery").galleria({
            /* ... */
            });
        } else {
            Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.min.js');
            $("#gallery").galleria({
            /* ... */
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just use the right doctype and make sure the page renders in standards mode, not compatibility mode?  Something like: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">`.

Comment: You are not supposed to have to design your web page to function in multiple modes.  You're supposed to pick the mode you want to design for, specify that and not worry about the other modes.  If a viewer forces the page into another mode, they get what they deserve.

Comment: @jfriend00: I am using the HTML 5 <!DOCTYPE html>, and I think I did that <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> does just that as it forces IE into standard mode.

Comment: @jfriend00: You can argue that way (although I certainly wouldn't as I try to make my site as compatible as possible), but it neither solves the IE 7 issue nor does it answer the jquery.support question.

Comment: Good luck designing for multiple modes then.  That is not supposed to be something you have to do, even when designing for good compatibility.  I don't know how to detect the mode in javascript which is why I didn't write an answer.  You can check to see if modernizr has this capability or not and see how they do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I use `jQuery.support` properly do check if the IE version is < 8 *or* the compatibility view is somehow still turned on?

[`jQuery.support` isn't designed to detect browser versions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), but to detect specific browser bugs.  If you can determine the source of this bug (possibly tested by the `.boxModel` property?), you could base your if-statement on that logic instead.

Feature-detection is more robust than simply detecting browser versions as the tests ideally will work against any browser that is buggy - not necessarily just those in the IE family.

If you don't want to track down the source of that browser bug (and thus find the correct `.support` test), then [this thread seems to give a slightly more "complete" test for browser version and compatbility mode detection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/6c282a47-3743-45bd-bfca-c2847a73485e).

Here's the code from that thread:

```
isIE8CompatMode() {
    return $.browser.msie
        && $.browser.version == 7.0
        && document.documentMode
        && document.documentMode == 8;
}
```

And of course you'd probably want to modify this to use `<` and `>` tests.

It still relies on `$.browser`, but seems to do extra detection for compatibility mode as well (via [the IE-specific `document.documentMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about jQuery.support and the .boxModel hint which I will check. The code you provided works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is plain javascript, not jQuery. You could use documentMode. See here [Determining Document Compatibility Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx). and here [documentMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, the document.compatMode looks promising. Although it leaves the jquery context.

Answer (score 2):

From the above, this is what I am using for IE7 Document or IE7 Compatabilty mode.

```
var IE7BrowserMode = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7.0);
var IE7DocumentMode = ($.browser.msie && document.documentMode && document.documentMode == 7);
return( IE7BrowserMode || IE7DocumentMode );
```

Comment: Thanks. A variation of Merlyns answer.